Enforcing VPN Usage for Salesforce Service Cloud Voice with Amazon Connect for Indian Agents
I’m working on a Salesforce Service Cloud Voice integration with Amazon Connect, and we have agents based in India. To comply with TRAI regulations, we need to ensure that agents are using a VPN when taking calls from the India region.
I have a few questions about how to enforce this:

Can we require agents to be connected to a VPN before logging into Omni-Channel or taking calls?

If an agent disconnects from the VPN after connecting, is there a way to automatically disconnect them from taking calls or prevent them from receiving new calls?


Essentially, we need to enforce that agents can only take calls if they are connected to the VPN. Any guidance or examples on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
